# How can I find the last key of an associative array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$breadcrumb = array(
    'home' => 'http://samplelink',
    'projects' => 'http://samplelink/projects',
    'project info' => 'http://samplelink/projects/3',
);
```

And I loop them:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <?php if(isset($breadcrumb)) { ?>
    <?php $last_key = end(array_keys($breadcrumb)); ?>
        <?php foreach($breadcrumb as $name => $link) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</ol>
```

And I want to add a `class='active'` in the last `li`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: my question where last li should be in the top or bottom ?

Comment: Just put this statement into the li to add a `class='active'` like `<li <?php if($name == $last_key) echo 'class="active"'; ?>>....</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `end` and `key` in order to get last key of array. Please try this code :

```
$breadcrumb = array(
    'home' => 'http://samplelink',
    'projects' => 'http://samplelink/projects',
    'project info' => 'http://samplelink/projects/3',
);

<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <?php if(isset($breadcrumb)) { ?>
    <?php 
    end($breadcrumb)
    $last_key = key($breadcrumb); 
    ?>
        <?php foreach($breadcrumb as $name => $link) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" <?php if($name==$last_key) { echo "active";}?>><?php echo $name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</ol>
```

> 1) end() advances array 's internal pointer to the last element, and
>   returns its value.
>
> 2) key() returns the index element of the current array position.

Demo : https://eval.in/524280

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `$name==$last_key` to make `li class=active` as below :

```
$breadcrumb = array(
    'home' => 'http://samplelink',
    'projects' => 'http://samplelink/projects',
    'project info' => 'http://samplelink/projects/3',
);

<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <?php if(isset($breadcrumb)) { ?>
    <?php $last_key = end(array_keys($breadcrumb)); ?>
        <?php foreach($breadcrumb as $name => $link) { ?>
            <li <?php if($name==$last_key){ ?>class="active"<?php }?> ><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be just to add a ternary on the `li` tag:

```
<li <?php echo ($name === $last_key) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a></li>
```